# Looking for LEGO parts in a different color

Tags: clone-brands, colour

I was wondering if you could assist me in my search for clone-brand bricks Technic parts.

I am in need of the following:

| Design Number | Wanted Color | Description | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71685 | Earth Blue | Panel 2 x 3 x 1, No. 1 | 1 piece |
| [42545](https://rebrickable.com/parts/42545/technic-panel-car-mudguard-arched-13-x-2-x-5/) | Earth Blue | Shell 5 x 13 x 2 with 4.85 Hole, No. 1 | 4 |
| [71709](https://rebrickable.com/parts/71709/technic-panel-3-x-7-x-1/) | Earth Blue | Flat Panel 3 x 7, No. 1 | 4 pieces |
| [93606](https://rebrickable.com/parts/93606/slope-curved-4-x-2-no-studs/) | Earth Blue | Brick with Bow 2 x 4 | 2 pieces |
| [40490](https://rebrickable.com/parts/40490/technic-beam-1-x-9-thick/) | Earth Blue | Technic 9M Beam | 12 pieces |
| [42195](https://rebrickable.com/parts/42195/technic-driving-ring-connector-smooth-2-rounded-and-2-flat-side-walls/) | Earth Blue | Cross Axle Extension 3M | 2 pieces |
| [42128](https://rebrickable.com/parts/32016/technic-axle-and-pin-connector-angled-3-1575/) | Earth Blue | Angle Element 157.5 Degrees [7](https://rebrickable.com/parts/85984/slope-30-1-x-2-x-23/) | 2 pieces |
| [59443](https://rebrickable.com/parts/59443/technic-axle-connector-smooth-with-x-hole-orientation/) | Earth Blue | Cross Axle Extension 2M | 4 pieces |
| [65487](https://rebrickable.com/parts/65487/technic-pin-connector-hub-with-1-pin-with-friction-ridges-lengthwise-square-holes/) | Earth Blue | Single Bush(ing) 2M Diameter 4.9 | 4 pieces |
| [85984](https://rebrickable.com/parts/85984/slope-30-1-x-2-x-23/) | Transparent (Clear) Red | Roof Tile 1 x 2 x 2/3, ABS | 6 pieces |

A fellow LEGO Technic Builder on “Bricklink” directed me to you. He suggested that you might have the parts in the color that I need hopefully this is so. I have tried LEGO, BrickLink, BrickOwl, BrickSet to locate the above parts in the LEGO Earth Blue color and the roof tile in transparent red (I do not think anyone makes this part in transparent red.)

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Here we are trying our best to answer questions like yours, however we are not communicating outside website (thus no emails) or trading bricks, so I have removed last section of your question.

Comment: I've linked your parts to Rebrickable for elements I could identify. Rebrickable (as well Bricklink) is using so-called "community" naming for LEGO elements, which often has a better description and is less confusing than LEGO naming.

Comment: Did you mean [71682](https://rebrickable.com/parts/71682/technic-panel-fairing-2-x-3-x-1/) (aka:  [Panel 2 x 3 x 1](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-white-panel-2-x-3-x-1-71682)) rather than 71685 (which does not appear to exist)?

Comment: Hi Howard, and welcome to Bricks :) To be clear we are purely a question and answer site, and don't stock, sell or manufacture elements. I think you also need to search for "[Dark Blue](https://rebrickable.com/colors/272/dark-blue/)" as that appears to be the colour most other sites use for LEGO's "Earth Blue".

Answer (score 1):

A number of those elements are available from [webrick.com](https://www.webrick.com/), you can upload a list to match with their inventory - remember to search for colour Dark Blue - 140, as that's what most sites call LEGO's Earth Blue.